# Single Store getting SQLSTATE: 42S01 namespace already exists error while using Recursive CTE in multi-threaded environment

Tags: common-table-expression, singlestore

Getting namespace already existing error in Singlestore while using recursive CTE
in mutlti threaded environment.

I have a table in db that contains enitire tree data id, parent_id and name
and the root node having parent_id values as zero.
My Requirement is based on name i need flattened data till root
(node --> Parent-->GrandParent  ------   Root)
By using CTE i'm able get the required data.

let me know the better approach as well for this

Below are the details
Singlestore version 8.1.32
Variables
allow_materialize_cte_with_union = TRUE
materialize_ctes = AUTO

Table:  AccountTree

| Id | Parent_ID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 0 | A |
| 105 | 101 | B |
| 106 | 105 | BA |
| 107 | 105 | BB |
| 108 | 106 | C |
| 109 | 108 | D |
| 110 | 107 | E |

If input name is C then my required Output is

| Id | Parent_ID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 0 | A |
| 105 | 101 | B |
| 106 | 105 | BA |
| 108 | 106 | C |

QUERY:
**With Recursive FlattenedTree as(
Select id, parent_id from AccountTree where name in (‘C’)
UNION ALL
Select t.id, t.parent_id from AccountTree t
JOIN FlattenedTree  as ft on t.id = ft. parent_id
) Select distinct * from AccountTree at
Join FlattenedTree ft on at.id = ft.id**

With the help of recursive CTE able to get the above results, but whereas in multi-threaded environment I’m getting the below error. (Each thread will have a separate connection object.)

**Exception:**
Out of 100 instances(Threads) i'm getting the below error on 2-5 instances.

SQLSTATE: 42S01
Leaf error (memsql url) Arrangement ‘iter_FlattenedTree_21’ already exists in namespace ‘msql_testenv_col’::’temp_1_244244_8’